# Information about locked folder or file

Tags: windows-7

if I have, for example, some locked file or folder, how can I get information about who locked (it is in use by another program) my file or folder without having to install other programs?

Is there any way to view this info in task manager?

Comment: Wait, what exactly do you mean by “locked”? Do you mean it is in-use? Is it encrypted? Do you no longer have access privileges to it?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/). It easier to use than programs from sysinternals but it will install bing toolbar by default

Comment: There is a portable version available as well.

Comment: …which addresses the part of the question that specifically says *without having to install other programs*.

Answer (score 2):

No, the Task Manager does not have the ability to display open (file) handles.

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) ([GUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_user_interface)) and [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) ([CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface)) are Microsoft tools that can do it. They are not included with Windows, but don’t have to install them, you can simply extract them from the ZIP files and run them. You can also run them directly from the website via the `Live.Sysinternals.com` link on the side.

In Process Explorer, you can press <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>, then enter the filename (or part of the filename) and click `Search`. ProcExp will display a list of processes that have open handles to the specified file. Double-clicking on an entry in the search-results list will jump to that item in the process tree where you can get more information about it by pressing <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd>. In the processes’ Properties dialog box, you can see the user that ran the process in the User field (go figure).

Comment: any ideas, without installing those tools?

Comment: You don’t have to install them, you can run them directly from the site (assuming that you have admin privileges). But I think it’s more important to first figure out what you mean by “locked”.

Comment: thanks but what about folders with a lot of files?

Comment: What about them? Do you mean you have a folder in which many of the files are locked? Just specify the folder in your search to view all the open handles.

Comment: thanks for the answer but if for example I don't have internet and can't download this program, what am I supposed to do? do I have any system infromation for this?

Comment: No idea. I can’t think of anything that comes with Windows that would allow you to copy a locked file.

Comment: @downvoter, got a problem hit-and-run down-voter? I wouldn’t know since you didn’t bother to leave a comment. *sigh*

Comment: @Synetech - There is always [Hobocopy](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/backupcopy-files-that-are-in-use-or-locked-in-windows), thought not included with Windows (hence needed to be d/l'd) for copying files locked by another process.

Answer (score 1):

Under Windows 7 you can use `Resource Monitor` - either from Task Manager, or directly (enter `resmon` into `Run` box).  Then select CPU, enter part of name into search box in `Associated handles` to see a list of proceses.

Following screenshot should explain it better: [image]